# .Net core 2.0 WCF Server side Roadmap

Tags: wcf, .net-core

Anyone have knowledge on .Net Core 2.0 WCF Serverside roadmap? Does Microsoft have plan to support .Net Core 2.0 with WCF Server side in near feature?

Comment: Microsoft is asking for feedback on this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/whereismysolution/2017/09/08/we-want-your-feedback/

Comment: Thank you Ricardo. I have provided the feedback

Answer (score 5):

They mentioned a few times that they have no intention of doing so. I'll try to find some relevant quotes.

Comment: Ahh, I can't find any definitive answer from a MS employee anywhere :/ The answers in the thread @Sanket mentioned seem to leave a little bit of possibility. So I guess the current state is that they don't currently support it, but who knows what future will bring.

Comment: Yes Michal. You are right. There is no clear answer in github.

Answer (score 1):

On June 7, 2019, the .NET Foundation [announced Core WCF](https://dotnetfoundation.org/blog/2019/06/07/welcoming-core-wcf-to-the-net-foundation) which is:

> a new community owned OSS project under the .NET Foundation with its initial code donated from a WCF team member at Microsoft. Core WCF is not intending to be a 100% compatible port of WCF to .NET Core, but aims to allow porting of many WCF contract and service implementations with only a change of namespace.
>
> Initially, it will be for HTTP and TCP SOAP services on-top of Kestrel, which are the most commonly used transports on .NET Framework.
>
> This project is not yet ready for production but needs people to get involved and help get it there faster. If you are interested in this, or want more details about the project, then we encourage you to go and explore the Core WCF project on GitHub.

Previously, on May 6 at Build 2019, [Microsoft announced](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-is-the-future-of-net/) that no other features (other than those already coming in .NET Core 3.0) would be ported from the .NET Framework and WCF Server developers that want to build a new app on .NET core they should use ASP.NET Core Web APIs or gRPC.